# Проблема с функцие strcut_s();

Tags: c++

```
    char mass[2][1000];
    char mass2[6][1000];
    int r = 0;
    int s = 0;
    ifstream fs("file1.txt");
    if (!fs.is_open()) { cout << "Файл не открыт!\n"; return 0; }
    while (!fs.eof())
    {
        fs.getline(mass[r], 1000); 
        cout << mass[r] << endl;
        r++;
    }
    fs.close();

    ifstream fs2("file2.txt");
    if (!fs2.is_open()) { cout << "Файл не открыт!\n"; return 0; }
    int p = 0;
    while (!fs2.eof())
    {
        fs2.getline(mass2[p], 1000);
        s++;
        cout << mass2[p] << endl;
        p++;
    }
    fs.close();

    int k = s;
    r = 0;

for (r=0;r<k;r++)
    {
        strcat_s(mass2[r],mass[r]);
        cout << mass2[r];

    };
```

В первом массиве 6 строк в другом 2 нужно прсоеденить к строкам 1 соответсвущие из 2. Но когда использую функцию strcat из за разного размера после добавления 2 строк выдет ошибку.

Comment: Что значит "соответствующие", если в одном массиве 6 строк, а в другом 2? Как определяется "соответствие"? И почему в заголовке некая `strcut_s`?

Answer (score 0):

Когда пишете на с++, то нужно писать на с++. А у Вас "майкрософт си". Используйте std::string и все станет сильно проще.

Теперь к ошибке. Почему то студия не отслеживает подобные ошибки. Но посмотрите на сигнатуру функции `strcat_s`

```
errno_t strcat_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource
);
```

Там три аргумента, а у Вас только два... И строка

```
strcat_s(mass2[r],mass[r]);
```

должна выглядеть как минимум так

```
strcat_s(mass2[r],1000, mass[r]);
```

И что бы два раза не отвечать, паттерн

```
while (!fs.eof())
    {
    ...
}
```

плохой. Он будет читать лишнюю, несуществующую строку в конце файла. Лучше писать так

```
while (fs.getline(mass[r], 1000))
{
    cout << mass[r] << endl;
    r++;
}
```

вот только если в файле будет больше 2 строк, будет беда.

Comment: У этой функции есть перегрузка для двух аргументов, принимающая ссылку на С-style массив первым аргументом и использующая его размер. Ну и ошибка (деталей которой оп не раскрыл) явно не из-за этого.